# Display time/clock in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using below method to display time in my app?

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTime();
    this.date = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
 getTime() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.time = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "HH:mm:ss");
      this.getTime();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

this code is working fine but after some time application getting crashed.
is there any alternative way to display time in angular4/5/6?

Comment: `setInterval` is spawning an extra parallel interval every time it's called, why does `getTime` call itself recursively? Also why don't you put the pipe in the template, then just do `this.time = new Date();`?

Comment: will try and update

Comment: [performance] this is wrong way of displaying clock on the screen. Every time interval is finished for 1000ms Angular event listener is triggered.  Try ngZone from @angular/core and run runOutsideAngular method in it

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Inside component.ts

```
  time = new Date();
  rxTime = new Date();
  intervalId;
  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    // Using Basic Interval
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.time = new Date();
    }, 1000);

    // Using RxJS Timer
    this.subscription = timer(0, 1000)
      .pipe(
        map(() => new Date()),
        share()
      )
      .subscribe(time => {
        this.rxTime = time;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

Inside component.html

```
Simple Clock:
<div>{{ time | date: 'hh:mm:ss a' }}</div>
RxJS Clock:
<div>{{ rxTime | date: 'hh:mm:ss a' }}</div>
```

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ihpcnz)

Comment: @Santhosh Please check the working demo link added to the answer.

Comment: I would also suggest to store and clear the inveral, like below :
`ngOnInit() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      this.time = new Date();
    }, 1000);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }`

Comment: It's helpful to explain *why* this works, and why the OP's original code didn't. Otherwise they don't learn anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the suggestion, I think you have already explained why it wasn't working in your previous comment.

Comment: Comments are *temporary*, though, most people will just read the top/accepted answer.

Comment: Where is the RxJS part OP asked for in this answer?

Comment: I love this answer!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use observables:

```
private _time$: Observable<Date> = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  map(tick => new Date()),
  shareReplay(1)
);

get time() {
  return this._time$;
}
```

And in your html:

```
{{ time | async | date: 'hh:mm:ss a' }}
```

**Benefit:** When you use `async` pipe in the HTML, you no longer need to consider subscribing and unsubscribing and worry about memory leaks. It is totally safe and easy to use!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative using an observable and "onPush" change detection

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'time',
    template: "{{ $time | async | date: 'hh:mm:ss a' }}",
    styleUrls: ['./time.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TimeComponent {
    public $time: Observable<Date> = timer(0, 1000).pipe(map(() => new Date()));
}
```