# How to set current time dynamically in a variable typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm working on a app which I should set messages according to current time based on hours.

For ex if time is: `23:35:2` I should set a string to `Good night <user name>` and if the time goes `4:00:0` I want to set `Good morning <user name>` accordingly.

Currently I'm writing the logic in angular service's `BehaviourSubject`. I get the current time by using javascript. But after I console logged the value the time is statically there.

```js
let currentDate = new Date();
let time = currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
console.log(time);
```

So I have set a `BehaviourSubject` and tried getting the time dynamically but the value is still static.

Below is my service file code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
  
  private time: BehaviorSubject<string>;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getDate() {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    let time = currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
    console.log(time);
    return this.time.next(JSON.stringify(time));
  }   

}
```

and tried calling it in my home file like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    return this.appService.getDate();
  }
```

I'm getting error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next')`

I'm barely new to angular bear with me. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: If I'm reading this right (toy example) you want to be able to put a button on the page and have it go from black to yellow and back to black again as the time changes?

To accomplish that you need to check the time at each interval step (polling) and make the update each step. FWIW polling frequently can cause poor performance.

Comment: can you show me an example of that, it will be more helpful.

Comment: Have a look at this (clock with rxjs interval, you'd need to add/change a value that would specifiy which button to use of course): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289078/display-time-clock-in-angular

Comment: With regards to the behavioralsubject -- it looks like your issue is you're not initializing it. In the constructor you'll probably want something like `this.time = new BehavioralSubject(currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds())`

Comment: can we get the time as actual time but not string ?

Comment: FWIW -- I wouldn't create a service for this since it isn't shared state and it's easily derivable globally

Comment: What do you mean as actual time? a number? A date object?

Comment: A number or date string anything that is dynamically console logged. I'm sorry if I make it very difficult to explain

Comment: Nothing is dynamically console logged -- the console shows the point in time snapshot of the value(s)

Comment: What if we can log between time intervals... like when the string or date change it triggers a function

Comment: You can do that (usually it is done w/ setTimeout or setInterval) but that's calling a function every n seconds -- not, strictly speaking, watching a clock variable change.

I understand the misconception now -- you're thinking about the clock as a constantly updating variable I'd instead think of the clock as a function that returns the number of seconds between now and Jan 1 1970.

Comment: Wow, I'm clear now. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to trigger an event every n seconds you can use the setInterval/setTimeout methods.

If you want to see how long something is running -- really what the date object is doing is saying okay the start was x seconds after 1/1/1970 and the end is y seconds after 1/1/1970 so it took y-x seconds

Comment: Check this if this works for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gsyjwm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts

Comment: What navnath has done there is use the rxjs interval (which I believe is setInterval under the hood) to invoke the function every 1000ms (1 second) and update the variable holding the clock data

What he's done is created a ever-changing variable to hold the latest clock from the date functions -- if you console log that value it wouldn't change, since the console is a snapshot

Comment: This is exactly what I need, Thanks move it to the answer I'll accept it. Only one more question. Does this affect the performance of the app ?

Comment: I think it does, since  we are triggering events every sec  but if you want you can increase interval timing like for every 5/10sec or more, Which will definitely reduce the load on your `callback queue` up to some extend, and when the user leaves that component it will unsubscribe, async pipe

Comment: Great then.. It will fit for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In service

```
  date = new Date();
  
  getDate() {
    return interval(1000).pipe(map(_ => this.getDateTime()));
  }

  // get new time by adding + sec
  private getDateTime() {
    this.date.setSeconds(this.date.getSeconds() + 1);
    return (
      this.date.getHours() +
      ':' +
      this.date.getMinutes() +
      ':' +
      this.date.getSeconds()
    );
  }
```

In your component :

```
 time$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    this.time$ = this.appService.getDate();
  }
```

In template

```
Time {{ this.time$ | async }}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gsyjwm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts)

If you want to increase delay time to the interval ex. for every 5 sec just change `interval(5000)` parameter as well as here `this.date.setSeconds(this.date.getSeconds() + 5);`

Comment: This works perfectly, I have changed the interval to 5000 but the inital rendering took more time

Comment: At initial also it will begin with 5sec

Comment: That's too sad does that have any workaround? I want to display that immediately as possible in dom later on I can show the dynamic value

Comment: use `timer(1000, 5000).` instead of `interval`. It will delay 1 sec for begin then 5sec afterwards

Comment: Oops I get this error `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SchedulerLike'.`

Comment: `return timer(1000, 5000).pipe(map((_) => this.getDateTime()));`

Comment: I'm ashamed of being too dumb, I'll learn rxjs soon as possible thank you for your support. Have a good day :)

Comment: Don't forget to change here also `this.date.setSeconds(this.date.getSeconds() + 5);`